# related_name argument required

Tags: django, django-models

I've recieved the following error and I'm not sure how to handle this in my model.

```
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'UserCart.state_tax' or 'UserCart.fed_tax'.
userorders.UserCart.state_tax: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'UserCart.state_tax' clashes with reverse accessor for 'UserCart.other_tax'.
```

models.py

```
class UserCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None) 
    state_tax = models.ForeignKey(Tax, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)    
    fed_tax = models.ForeignKey(Tax, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is here necessary, since you have *two* references from `UserCart` to the `Tax` model. This thus means that the relation in reverse (from `Tax` to `UserCart`) can not be `usercart_set`, since then it is not clear which relation we use in reverse.

We thus should at least give a related name to one of the relations (that is different from `usercart_set`). For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None) 
    state_tax = models.ForeignKey(
        Tax,
        related_name='state_usercarts',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    fed_tax = models.ForeignKey(
        Tax,
        related_name='fed_usercarts',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
```

> **Note**: you might want to make use of [**`get_user_model`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) over a reference to `User` itself. If you later change your user model, then the `ForeignKey` will automatically refer to the new user model.

Comment: Thanks. Does this in any way change how I will call instances of UserCart in my views?

Comment: @JasonHoward: not per se if you did not query from the `Tax` model to the `UserCart` model (but you probably did not do that, because there was already an error on that).